# One page theme Bootstrap Navigation Link does not direct to another page, while it works for anchors inside the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I have been using a bootstrap one page theme in my ASP MVC 5 app. Since it is one page, all the navigation links points to anchors inside the page. Then I needed an additional link to direct to another page, but it does not work. When I see the source code, the href is just fine, the hover is also fine, but when clicked it does nothing. Please help me spot the problem.

the problem is here:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/ShoppingCart">Cart (2)</a></li>
```

here is the html code:

```
<nav class="fixed-top" id="navigation" style="top: 0px; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12 center">
                <!-- LOGO -->
                <a class="brand pull-left" href="./">
                    <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="Treble">
                </a>
                <!-- END LOGO -->
                <!-- MOBILE MENU BUTTON -->
                <div class="mobile-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav- collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- END MOBILE MENU BUTTON -->
                <!-- MAIN MENU -->
                <ul id="main-menu" class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <li class=""><a href="#page-welcome">Home</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#page-product">Product</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#page-about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page-news">News</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#page-contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="/ShoppingCart">Cart (2)</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- END MAIN MENU -->
                <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->
                <div class="social-icons pull-right" id="navRight">
                    <a href="mailto:info@panairsan.com"   class="phoneNumber">info@panairsan.com</a>
                    <a href="tel:+62215807881" class="phoneNumber logOffPadding">+62 (21) 580 7881</a>
                </div>
                <!-- END SOCIAL ICONS -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the related css classes:

```
.fixed-top {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

#navigation #main-menu {
float: right;
}
#navigation .social-icons {
display: none;
}
```

I think that is all about the code, nothing else seems to be effecting the link. Please let me know if you need more code to solve this weird problem.

I tried this one also:

```
<a href="./ShoppingCart">
```

Adding a dot, like the logo that is able to go to home page (refresh the page), but still does not work.

Thanks

**Update**

I use **jquery.scrollTo**. Maybe there is something with this plugin?

The theme I use is this one:

[Wrapbootsrap - Treble One Page Theme](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/treble-one-page-responsive-theme-WB089478D)

**UPDATE about jquery.scrollTo**

I keep searching, and I am narrowing the problem to jquery.scrollTo. It seems that the plugin is preventing the page from going anywhere. Anywone here is experienced with jquery.scrollTo?

**UPDATE Routing Mechanism:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "percobaan2.Controllers" }
        );
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

the main problem: the link is active but it does not direct to the linked page. It does not even direct to a 404 page or anything. It just does not execute the href location.

Comment: can you show the working example for the issue in fiddle or plunker

Comment: here is the working template I use. It is exactly like this: http://gridelicious.com/themes/treble/demo/

Comment: how do you handle the rounting?

Comment: I pretty much sure that the routing is just normal. I mean, <a href="/ShoppingCart"> is just working anywhere else but not in the navigation menus. It just won't click sir. Tesekkurler

Answer (score 3):

In the href link call the class "external" like this:

```
<a href="./ShoppingCart"class="external">
```

Answer (score 0):

i experienced the same some of the element may overlap your link, just increase the z-index of the link separately

Comment: I am sorry sir, What would that increasing the z-index mean? I have no idea :( Updated: I am searching and I think I have the idea. While I am searching, I would be glad if you could show me how to do id. thanks

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention: when I clicked the link, the class changed into "active". Does this mean the click is still blocked?

Comment: from ur answer i identify that there is no problem with z-index, the problem is with your routing. can you just show your routing mechanism

Comment: I updated the route config, which is the built in configuration. nothing fancy. I want to add something. in the navigation bar, there are three link types elements, there is LOGO, MAIN MENU and SOCIAL ICONS. I tried the LOGO and SOCIAL ICONS with <a href="/ShoppingCart">  and all works, but not the MAIN MENU. It drives me crazy.

Comment: I have checked the spelling like enough sir, I did not miss it I am sure

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue in my project.

The file `plugin.js` was causing the trouble, in my case, because the template itself was a one-page template.

I commented-out the line:

```
self.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.handleClick, self));
```

And the links in the nav just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the template.  The application.js file has a script that makes this happen. So you should be able to just remove the 
scroll class from the a tag to allow redirect.

```
/* use class="scroll" on the a element to activate*/
  $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //calculate destination place
      var dest = 0;
      if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
          dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
      } else {
          dest = $(this.hash).offset().top - 50;
      }
      //go to destination
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: dest
      }, 1500, 'swing');

    /* Fix jumping of navigation. */
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).trigger('scroll');
    }, 900);

    return false;

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution on this page:

[a href is not going to other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008506/a-href-is-not-going-to-other-pages/35008635?noredirect=1#comment57744967_35008635)

open up your console and then click the inspection tools and then click on the link to open what script runs when you click on that link. you have to state an if statement to say: if (".navbar a" =! ".external"){here goes the rest of li that have external links and now it works}

and then add the external links to the li tags that have external links.

```
if (".navbar a" =! ".external"){
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 900, function(){

      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in the smooth scroll function `event.preventDefault();`
the best and most simple way to do it would be to add a `.not('.ext_link')`
to the smooth scroll function witch will look something like:

```
$(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").not('.ext_link').on('click', function(event) {
```

and the add to all the external links a `class="ext_link"`
Hope that works for you...