# a href is not going to other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have this navigation menu that has few links to different part of the same index.html like a `href="#about"` or a `href="#product"` but when i put a `href="reservation.html"` it does not go to that page. in other word, all same-page internal anchor link works but external links (to other pages) does not work. any idea why? 
I am using bootstrap:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="image/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="font">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">EVENTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Wedding</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bachelor Party</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prom</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="reservation.html">RESERVATION</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: not work means anchor clicking has no effect or showing error page?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what do you mean? Does it do nothing or does it give you an error?

Comment: Are `index.html` and `reservation.html`, both, at the same directory/folder?

Comment: they are in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

OK problem solved it seems that at the bottom of the index.html of this one-page template there is this line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 900, function(){

      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  });
```

the links as i guessed are prevented by default so i added an if statement saying:

```
 if (".navbar a" =! ".external"){here goes the rest of li that have external links and now it works}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to know about relative path

`/` root

`./` current directory

`../` parent of the current directory.

Try this,

```
<a href="./index.html"><img src="image/logo.png"></a>
```

Comment: @AliRJ where is index.html and reservation.html? both are in same directory? and what is the result you've got ?

Comment: yes they are. when i click on reservation it doesnt even change anything in the url, there must be preventDefault somewhere when i exclude jquery.min.js the links works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `href="/reservation.html"` if the exact link is `www.website.com/reservation.html`.

Comment: Try putting the entire link to check if it actually exists.

Comment: the link doesnt even change in the url there must be e.preventDefualt somewhere. when i exclude jquery.min.js it works