# One page theme smooth-scrolling Bootstrap Navigation Link does not work when trying to open other pages, but it does work for anchors inside the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, smooth-scrolling

I need to have some of my navbar buttons redirect for instance back to my start page. It seems the smooth-scroller coding needs the menu items to direct to hashtag anchors for the menu items to function and this does work, but when I try to redirect to another page entirely, nothing happens. There is no error and there is no div covering the button.

A solution I saw on here involved adding a statement to the scroller code to disable the need for hashtags for specific external links, but I don't know how to code this and my template's code is dissimilar to the one mentioned in the thread. I would in other words need a code that states to do the regular actions onclick, as long as the button does not have the class "ext-link". See the link below for more specific details.  [One page theme Bootstrap Navigation Link does not direct to another page, while it works for anchors inside the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484228/one-page-theme-bootstrap-navigation-link-does-not-direct-to-another-page-while)

I'm not entirely sure the below is the right code, but it seems like it. How would I rewrite it to include an "if click and not class=ext-link" case so that I could enable external links from my site-root for my navbar?

```
jQuery('#scrollToContent').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.scrollTo("#portfolio", 1000, { offset:-(jQuery('#header .top').height()), axis:'y' });
});

jQuery('.nav > li > a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.scrollTo(jQuery(this).attr('href'), 400, { offset:-(jQuery('#header .top').height()), axis:'y' });
})

jQuery(window).scroll( function() {
   //setHeaderBackground();
});
```

Comment: [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) appears to offer at least some insight, if not a solution.

Comment: Interesting article, but it unfortunately didn't help me at all. I was thinking something along the lines of wrapping the aforementioned whole script in the likes of an if-statement per the following:

 `if ('.nav > li > a' != ".ext-link"){}`

But that didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this right you can modify the second click even handler with this code and it should work:

```
jQuery('.nav > li > a').click(function(e){
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    if (!$this.hasClass('ext-link')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.scrollTo($this.attr('href'), 400, { offset:-(jQuery('#header .top').height()), axis:'y' });
    }
})
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, friend. You totally saved the day! +1 @Timo